# R - Calculate MLE of combined distribution

Tags: r, normal-distribution, mle

I have a given dataset with 1000 values, which is a combination of two normal distributions N(y1,1) and N(y2,1). The density looks like the following:

[image]

I want to calculate the portion of N(y1,1) and N(y2,1) in the dataset and the two means y1 and y2. This is my current approach:

```
z <- #Dataset as vector with 1000 entries#
lik <- function(mu1, mu2, part) -sum(part*dnorm(z, mu1, 1, log=TRUE) + (1-part)*dnorm(z, mu2, 1, log=TRUE))
mle <- mle(lik, start=list(mu1=-7, mu2=5, part=0.33))
```

But this gives me the following error message:

```
Error in solve.default(oout$hessian) : 
    Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I redefined the likelihood to use `log()` instead of argument `log = TRUE`.

Oddly enough, the following works in spite of the warnings. Note that they are *warnings*, not errors.

```
library(stats4)

set.seed(7850)    # Make the results reproducible
z <- sample(c(rnorm(333, -7, 1), rnorm(667, 5, 1)))

plot(density(z))

lik2 <- function(mu1, mu2, part) -sum(log(part*dnorm(z, mu1, 1) + (1-part)*dnorm(z, mu2, 1)))
mle2 <- mle(lik2, start = list(mu1 = -6, mu2 = 6, part = 1/2))
#Warning messages:
#1: In log(part * dnorm(z, mu1, 1) + (1 - part) * dnorm(z, mu2, 1)) :
#  NaNs produced
#2: In log(part * dnorm(z, mu1, 1) + (1 - part) * dnorm(z, mu2, 1)) :
#  NaNs produced
#3: In log(part * dnorm(z, mu1, 1) + (1 - part) * dnorm(z, mu2, 1)) :
#  NaNs produced
#4: In log(part * dnorm(z, mu1, 1) + (1 - part) * dnorm(z, mu2, 1)) :
#  NaNs produced

mle2
#
#Call:
#mle(minuslogl = lik2, start = list(mu1 = -6, mu2 = 6, part = 1/2))
#
#Coefficients:
#       mu1        mu2       part 
#-7.1091780  4.9377339  0.3330038
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect. Strange thing that it doesn't work with `log = TRUE`

Comment: @Codey Note that `log(a*dnorm + b*dnorm)` is not equal to `a*log(dnorm) + b*log(dnorm)`.

Comment: Oh right, didn't thought about it at all. So mathematical `log(a*dnorm + b*dnorm)` is the correct solution anyways. Thanks